# Roots of a function with first Fourier coefficients equal

Tags: integration, roots, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a real continuous $2\pi$-periodic function, and $n$ a natural number such that for any natural number $k < n$, $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos(kx)\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin(kx)\,\mathrm dx \;.$$

How can we prove that $f$ has, at least, $2n$ roots in the interval $[0,2\pi[$?

I'm not sure if the periodicy assumption is really needed, as in that case it would just boil down to $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Besides, the continuity assumption is not enough to make the Fourier series converge towards $f$.

Comment: this is not true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650748/is-the-condition-sufficient

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.